# Do Ajax calls based on Checkbox selected data

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am new to Jquery and Ajax stuff. please Help me in acheving my solution.

Currenlty I am populating check boxes based on my model values and doing an ajax call to get list of countries for each selected value.

Now I am trying instead of displaying Model values if user clicks on All check box I need to pass All as  my selected value so that I can fetch all countries.

So below I added a new check box id saying checkBoxAll so how can I do ajax call if all is selected. Can I write if stmt?

```
   <div id="checkboxes">
   <% foreach (var manufacturer in Model.Manufacturer)
   {%>
<input type="checkbox" id="<%: manufacturer.Id %>" class="checkbox" value="<%: manufacturer.Description %>" /><%: manufacturer.Description %><br />
<%} %>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxAll" class="checkBoxAll" value="All" /> All <br />
<input type="button" value="GetCountries" class="brands" />
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(".brands").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var selected = "";
    var manu = "";
    var input = "";
    $("#checkboxes input:checked").each(function () {
        manu = $(this).val();
        selected = selected + "," + manu;
        $("#SelectedBrands").val(selected);
        });
    var productInput = "";
    var myUrl = "/Countries/GetCountiresForManufacturer/" + selected;
    $.ajax({
        url: myUrl,
        type: 'get',
        success: function (data) {
            productInput = data;
         $(".divNewCountriesList").html(productInput);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean a little bit your code.
When you get data back why you asign it to a new var you can use

```
$(div).html(data);


$('#checkboxes').each(function(){
     if(this.checked && $(this).hasClass("all")){ //or id
        //do something
     }else{
        //do something else
     }
});
```